# Program not working after the execution of the entire code

Tags: c++, char, symbols

so this code is supposed to cout the last "reverse_display" symbols in every word of a string at the beginning of the word, as follows:
cin>>
Oh, jingle bells, jingle bells, jingle all the way. Oh, what fun it is to ride in a one horse open sleigh.
3
cout<< 
hO, glejin llsbe, glejin llsbe, glejin all the way. hO, hatw fun ti si ot ider ni a one rseho peno ighsle.

Everything works fine, excpet for the fact that after the end of execution, the program stops working, without any particular reason I can see. I tried typing in a test cout at the end of the program, it executes, and then the program again stops working. I tried with without renter code hereeturn 0, but in vain. This is the bain of my existance, please help.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int check_if_reverse_display_overload (int, int);
int main ()
{
    string dumi="";
    string duma="";

    getline (cin,dumi);

    dumi.append(" ");

    int reverse_display, reverse_display_overload, i=0, k=0;

    cin>>reverse_display;

    for (int i=0; i< dumi.length(); i++)
    {

        if ((dumi[i]>='A' && dumi[i]<='Z') || (dumi[i]>='a' && dumi[i]<='z') || dumi[i]=='-' || ( dumi[i]>='0' && dumi[i]<='9'))
        {

            duma[k]=dumi[i];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (((dumi[i-1]>='A' && dumi[i-1]<='Z') || (dumi[i-1]>='a' && dumi[i-1]<='z') || dumi[i-1]=='-' || (dumi[i-1]>='0' && dumi[i-1]<='9'))  && i!=1)
            {
            reverse_display_overload=check_if_reverse_display_overload(reverse_display, k);

            for (int j=k-reverse_display_overload; j<k; j++)
            {
                cout<<duma[j];
            }
            for (int j=0; j<k-reverse_display_overload; j++)
            {
                cout<<duma[j];
            }

            duma="";
            k=0;
            }
            cout<<dumi[i];

        }

    }
// cout<<"bogomil rainov e pi4";
    return 0;
}

int check_if_reverse_display_overload (int reverse_display, int k)
{
    if (k==0)
    {

        return reverse_display;
    }
    if(reverse_display>k)
    {

        return check_if_reverse_display_overload(reverse_display-k, k);
    }
    else
    {

        return reverse_display;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just access an empty string (duma). You're invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: You can eliminate half of your compares by using `std::tolower` or `std::toupper`.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine helped me find the mistake.Its related to this piece of code. Its related to working outside of the array of the string duma. Although I still cannot understand the essence of this bug.

```
 if ((dumi[i]>='A' && dumi[i]<='Z') || (dumi[i]>='a' && dumi[i]<='z') || dumi[i]=='-' || ( dumi[i]>='0' && dumi[i]<='9'))
    {

        duma[k]=dumi[i]; // the error because of this line
        k++;
    }
```

Comment: At that point `duma` is empty, so `duma[k]` is out of range for any `k`. You could use `push_back` to add characters to the string.

Comment: _"Although I still cannot understand the essence of this bug."_ It's quite simple - you're writing to elements that do not exist.